# Not Able to watch my Cardano faucets when i query the node

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node, cardano-address, cardano-faucet

I am using following command to query node.
`./cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat payment.addr)    --testnet-magic 1097911063`
Getting the Faucets in preview testnet by the following site
https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/tools/faucet
The funding gets successful, also i can see the transaction hash on https://preview.cexplorer.io/tx ,But not getting faucets on node query.
Although my node is also synced to 64% with Alonzo era. Kindly guide me what i am missing.
Also i am using the latest cardano-node version ie. 1.35.4

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to be able to query your address after you just used the faucet, the node must be in sync (100%). The version 1.35.4 is correct, it is the only one that will sync your node to 100%.
Second, if you are on the preview testnet, the testnet magic is 2. The testnet magic 1097911063 is for the legacy testnet.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, ill check it again when it gets 100% synced. Also i checked my testnet magic from db created which shows me 1097911063. And if i query the node with magic 2 then it gives me error of "cardano-cli: HandshakeError (Refused NodeToClientV_13 "version data mismatch: NodeToClientVersionData {networkMagic = NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 1097911063}} /= NodeToClientVersionData {networkMagic = NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 2}}")"

Comment: If your magic in the db folder is 1097911063, then you are on the legacy testnet, not on preview.

Comment: To switch to preview, you need to stop the node, download the configuration files for preview from here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html, delete the db folder and start your node.
Also, 1.35.4 will never sync the legacy testnet to 100%. Only 1.35.2 will sync it to 100%.

Comment: Yah, I have tried the prepod testnet also, but its syncing doesn't go beyond 0.01% even after a whole day. With that syncing speed i am unable to get any faucets. Can you please recommend its solution. I have also tried cardano 1.35.3 (preview and also preprod), but again its not syncing enough then how can i get faucets and proceed with that?

Comment: Syncing on preview and preprod should be a matter of minutes, you are probably doing something wrong.
For preview and preprod use 1.35.4, 1.35.3 will still go for a while for preprod, but not for preview.
You should check the logs to see what the problem is. If you are not starting your node as a systemd service, take a look at the tutorial I wrote here: https://apexpool.gitbook.io/stake-pool-scripts/running-a-cardano-node
To see the logs if you set it like I described, run:
```journalctl -f -n 50 -u cardano-node.service```

Comment: Ok after alot of research, finally i got the solution. I checked my log, it was giving error of  `TrConnectError (Just 127.0.0.1:1337) 3.72.231.105:30000 Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 55>: invalid argument (Invalid argument)` . So i resolved this error by running the node with **host-addr 0.0.0.0** So final command is ```cardano-node run --config $HOME/cardano/preprod/config.json
--database-path $HOME/cardano/db
--socket-path $HOME/cardano/db/node.socket
--host-addr 0.0.0.0
--port 1337
--topology $HOME/cardano/preprod/topology.json```